# OpenCV linking problems with ROS

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, ubuntu-14.04, ros

I'm trying to compile [this](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam) project (following the instructions given). When building it with `rosmake`, I get a bunch of `undefined reference to cv::String::deallocate()` and `undefined reference to cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)`. I find curious that I'm getting an error just in those functions while the rest of the OpenCV functions seem to be working properly.

I know this happens because the linker can't find the objects where these functions were compiled to, but I'm kind of new to the ROS build system and can't find what's wrong.

I've tried using the `CMakeLists.txt` file provided, and also adding `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` and `target_link_libraries(xxx xxx ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})`, without that making any difference. I know OpenCV is installed and compiled properly (I've used it before), and I had installed ROS without any problems.

I'm using OpenCV 3, ROS Indigo, Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem - same error messages, same setup. I've managed to solve it, though I'm not exactly sure of the steps I did which actually contributed. As far as I can tell, it was due to a conflict of OpenCV versions - I think I had old versions of OpenCV cluttering my /usr/include and /usr/local. I uninstalled all OpenCV packages (including the ROS ones) and including my from-source install of OpenCV3 (also in /usr/local). Then I installed the ROS package vision_opencv, which seemed to install OpenCV 2.4.8 (incidentally the one recommended by LSD SLAM). Of course, this could be annoying if you need OpenCV3 for other things, but I now have that as a local install in my home directory (I couldn't figure out how to get ROS to link to this).

I think this solved the problem, the only issue remaining was that I got error messages saying  was not found. This was because the package install leaves it in  (similar for all module include files), whereas the make install step of the from-source install copies them into the parent folder. To get around this I simply edited the #include in the only file in which it is used (lsd_slam_core/src/IOWrapper/OpenCV/ImageDisplay_OpenCV.cpp). That seemed to solve it!

I hope this helps, I can give further details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am using OpenCV 3.1.0(Bleeding edge), ROS Indigo, Ubuntu 14.04. 
I ran in to similar trouble when trying to compile LSD-SLAM

I added:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3.1.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc imgcodecs)
```

I also added opencv libs to target link libs:

```
target_link_libraries(lsdslam ${FABMAP_LIB} g2o_core g2o_stuff csparse cxsparse g2o_solver_csparse g2o_csparse_extension g2o_types_sim3 g2o_types_sba X11 opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs)
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(lsd_slam_core)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
find_package(OpenCV 3.1.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc imgcodecs)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Release)

rosbuild_init() 

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(SuiteParse REQUIRED) # Apparently needed by g2o
find_package(X11 REQUIRED)

# FabMap
# uncomment this part to enable fabmap
#add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/openFabMap)
#include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/openFabMap/include)
#add_definitions("-DHAVE_FABMAP")
#set(FABMAP_LIB openFABMAP )

# Dynamic Reconfigure Services
rosbuild_find_ros_package(dynamic_reconfigure)
include(${dynamic_reconfigure_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake)
gencfg()

# SSE flags
rosbuild_check_for_sse()
add_definitions("-DUSE_ROS")
add_definitions("-DENABLE_SSE")

# Also add some useful compiler flag
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
   "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${SSE_FLAGS} -march=native  -std=c++0x"
) 

# Set source files
set(lsd_SOURCE_FILES
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/DataStructures/Frame.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/DataStructures/FramePoseStruct.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/DataStructures/FrameMemory.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/SlamSystem.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/LiveSLAMWrapper.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/DepthEstimation/DepthMap.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/DepthEstimation/DepthMapPixelHypothesis.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/util/globalFuncs.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/util/SophusUtil.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/util/settings.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/util/Undistorter.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Tracking/Sim3Tracker.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Tracking/Relocalizer.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Tracking/SE3Tracker.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Tracking/TrackingReference.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/IOWrapper/Timestamp.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/GlobalMapping/FabMap.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/GlobalMapping/KeyFrameGraph.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/GlobalMapping/g2oTypeSim3Sophus.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/GlobalMapping/TrackableKeyFrameSearch.cpp
)
set(SOURCE_FILES
  ${lsd_SOURCE_FILES}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/IOWrapper/ROS/ROSImageStreamThread.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/IOWrapper/ROS/ROSOutput3DWrapper.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/IOWrapper/OpenCV/ImageDisplay_OpenCV.cpp
)

include_directories(
  ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/Sophus
  ${CSPARSE_INCLUDE_DIR} #Has been set by SuiteParse
  ${CHOLMOD_INCLUDE_DIR} #Has been set by SuiteParse
)

# build shared library.
rosbuild_add_library(lsdslam SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(lsdslam ${FABMAP_LIB} g2o_core g2o_stuff csparse cxsparse g2o_solver_csparse g2o_csparse_extension g2o_types_sim3 g2o_types_sba X11 opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs)
rosbuild_link_boost(lsdslam thread)


# build live ros node
rosbuild_add_executable(live_slam src/main_live_odometry.cpp)
target_link_libraries(live_slam lsdslam)


# build image node
rosbuild_add_executable(dataset_slam src/main_on_images.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dataset_slam lsdslam)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multi-versions Opencv? if you have, maybe you should add the  path to `OpenCVConfig.cmake` into `CmakeList.txt`. Just under the `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)`，like so:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR "/home/ubuntu/src/opencv-3.1.0/build")
```

That's all.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the samme issue. Could not comment Osian's solution due to lack of rep, but this is the procedure I used:

```
sudo apt-get remove libopencv*
```

If you for some reason have OpenCV installed from source, enter your build directory and do:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Then finally

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```