# opencv3 linking from ROS kinetic

Tags: opencv, cmake, ros, clion

all!

I am trying to use OpenCV library in CLion project, but this is unsuccessful. I have opencv 3.2.0 installed with ROS kinetic at once (I can see it in /opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0 directory and I can import cv2 by python). But when I use such CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(visual_slam)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
set(OpenCV_DIR /opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_DIR})
add_executable(visual_slam ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

with the next simple code:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

  using namespace cv;

  int main()
  {
      return 0;
  }
```

I get the next error:

> CMakeFiles/visual_slam.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
>   /opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:664: undefined reference to`cv::String::deallocate()'
>   CMakeFiles/visual_slam.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
>   /opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:672: undefined reference to`cv::String::deallocate()'

Such error was discussed also in  [OpenCV linking problems with ROS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479379/opencv-linking-problems-with-ros), but is it really so necessary to uninstall completely and then install again OpenCV? Is there any more quick solution?

Second question, how to correctly add OpenCV from ROS to CMakeLists.txt? Current CMakeLists (look above) does not look like to be flexible. I've already tried to add

```
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(visual_slam ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} )
```

but the error is when CMake builds

```
 By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV",      but
 CMake did not find one.
 Could not find a package configuration file provided 
 by "OpenCV" (requested version 3) with any of the following names:

 OpenCVConfig.cmake
 opencv-config.cmake
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second error you are getting (namely the missing `OpenCV.cmake`) is actually not only related to the first one (the `undefined reference to`) but is the cause.

If `cmake` fails to find the OpenCV module the `${OpenCV_LIBS}` won't do a thing meaning that `target_link_libraries(visual_slam ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} )` doesn't link against the libraries your code requires. That said I also believe that it's `OpenCV_LIBS` instead of `OpenCV_LIBRARIES`.

You can of course specify the path where the `find_package(...)` command looks at to find `cmake` modules (I think it was the [`CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH) variable) or even manually specify the root folder of your OpenCV installation and manually handle all the things that the `OpenCV.cmake` handles for you.

Last but not least I'm not sure if ROS Kinetic uses the latest OpenCV (what you are using namely the v3.2). You should check that and if different versions are used (very likely), you will have to build all ROS OpenCV-related packages from scratch. You might ask "Why should I do that?". Well, to avoid compatibility issues and various weird errors that may or may not occur (depending on what OpenCV functionality you use) due to version X of OpenCV being used for the binary packages of ROS and version Y present on your system (with X != Y). I had to do that with PCL (Point Cloud Library) once and it took me several days to come to this conclusion since the errors that I was getting were (typical for C++) cryptic as hell. To avoid conflicts make sure that only the one version of OpenCV is present on your system (that is can be found by `cmake`) that you want to use with your ROS installation. That's also the reason why the ROS binary packages are shipped through the Ubuntu repos using dependencies that are resolved by the package manager (OpenCV, PCL etc.).

**PS:** Since I haven't used `Clion` I would also suggest (before doing anything I've mentioned above) to check if it's not some hidden `cmake`-related setting inside the IDE that screws things up.

Comment: Thank your for reply! The problem is solved, if I launch Clion from terminal. For details http://answers.ros.org/question/210534/jetbrains-clion-ide-setup-for-ros/

Comment: Ah, so the problem was IDE related. Same thing happens with Qt Creator (which I use) btw.